# `git commit -p`: can I get better diff, per chars?

Tags: git, git-diff

In such cases:
[image: git commit -p]
it is difficult to say - here was changed the indentation only or maybe also my cat updated a few chars. I know that exists for example [diff-so-fancy](https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy) where I can see the difference on the chars level, but there is no official out of the box solution?

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text. Post the text itself.

Comment: I agree with you but it is just an illustration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git diff` directly. It does have options for whitespace handling. -> `man git-diff`

Comment: Yes thank you but maybe was accidentally replaced some letter.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`--word-diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---word-diffltmodegt) option.

For the file

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

changed to

```
    The quick brown fox jumps over the sleepy dog
```

`git diff --word-diff` shows

```
   The quick brown fox jumps over the [-lazy-]{+sleepy+} dog
```

---

EDIT: Oh, I realized that your problem is the very long URL that is treated as a single word. [--word-diff-regex](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---word-diff-regexltregexgt) may help here.

I tried a different, but similar URL with `git diff --word-diff-regex="/|[^[:space:]]"`, which worked quite well. You might however want to improve that regex.

Comment: No way to use it inside `git commit -p`?

Comment: I did not find a way. The `--patch` and `--interactive` modes seem to work hunk-wise. Although `git add`s `patch --interactive` seems to have an option to split hunks into smaller ones, see [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#git-add-patch).

Comment: Yes, I use [S]plit, it is useful.